# Access shared data extension from child BU using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio

I am trying to access the value from a Data extension, using the below code. The code works fine if I pass the external key of the regular data extension. But when I pass the value of the shared data extension it does not return anything. Basically from the child BU it is not possible to access the shared data extension using the below code.

```
<script runat="server">
   Platform.Load("Core","1");
   
   var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var initDE = DataExtension.Init("external_key_of_Data_extension");
       var initDEData = initDE.Rows.Retrieve();
      
      Write("ANS:"+initDEData[1].Name)

</script>
```

Please can anyone tell me how to read from the shared data extension from child BU? should I change anything in the code?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it just doesn't work and I'll be happy if someone here proves me wrong.

I tried getting the data with `Rows.Retrieve()` (no, prefixing anything with `ENT.` does not work) and with WSProxy from the DataExtensionObject, but just can't get it to work.

The only real option you have is to surrender and add a data extension column you will use to get the row data with a lookup function. Call it `LookupBait`, make it a boolean that's always set to true, use any lookup function and shake your fist against the sky, because it should work, but just doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "ENT." in front of the shared data extension name.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_shared_data_extensions.htm&type=5